# プロパティで初期化した配列にメソッドから値を追加するとメモリリークが発生する

Tags: swift, macos

複数のメソッドからプロパティを操作したいのですがappendメソッドで値を追加するとメモリリークが発生します。

以下は簡素化したコードです。

```swift
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private var values: [Int] = []

    private func calc(count: Int) {
        for i in 0 ..< count {
            values.append(i)
            print("i = \(values[i])")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        calc(count: 5)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

これでメモリリークが発生する理由がわかりません。
何かコードが間違っているのでしょうか？

Xcode11.3です。バージョンアップ以前から同じところで悩んでいます。

どなたかお教え願えないでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `_ContiguousArrayStorage`はSwiftが配列などの処理で内部的に使用するデータ型で、"ContiguousArrayStorage leak"で検索すると多数の記事が引っかかりますが、極めて限定的なケースを除いて、確実な解決策・回避策は見当たりません。Swiftの実行時ライブラリ(またはLeaksツール)のバグであろうと思われるので、Appleにバグ報告した上で、すぐには実害が出ないことを祈りつつアプリ開発を続けるしかないだろうと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。やはりバグの可能性があるのですね。このようなコードは、みなさんよく使用するのではないかと思われますが、どのように対処なさっているのでしょうか。バグ報告し様子を見たいと思います。大変ありがとうございました。

Comment: フィードバックアシスタントでバグ報告を行いました。この質問に目を通していただいた方々にもお礼を申し上げたいです。ありがとうございました。